# Order between destruction of global object and atexit in C++

Tags: c++, atexit, order-of-execution, global-object

I wonder that can sure order between destruction of global object and `atexit` in C++

I have a global object and register `atexit` function like below:

```
static MyClass g_class;

void onExit()
{
    // do some destruction
}

int main()
{
    atexit(onExit);

    return 0;
}
```

I've found `onExit()` is invoked before `MyClass::~MyClass()` in Visual Studio 2012 and gcc4.7.2. Am I sure that `onExit` is always invoked before global object(like `g_class`) destruction?

I wonder global object register order and `atexit` register order use same order table.
Or there is no relation between global object order and `atexit` order?

Edited : Sorry I wrote a mistake. I'm so confused while tidying example code. `onExit()` is invoked before ~MyClass().

Comment: I suspect that order isn't 100% sure to be defined. Why do you care?

Comment: Create another global object before `MyClass` and call `atexit( onExit  )` in its constructor to check.

Comment: Want to control lifetime of objects, use dynamic ones.

Comment: Actually, I have a singleton memory manager object is destructed by atexit and global object is using member variable managed by that memory manager. So global object is destructed before memorymanager destruction by atexit.

Comment: @zelon: [off-topic] As an irrelevant note, using `static` keyword on a file-scope (global scope) variable probably does **not** do what you think it does. That is, the `static` in your example code is redundant.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

**UPDATE:** *The OP made some confusion, and it seems VC11 does indeed behave as specified by the C++11 Standard. The following answer was written in the assumption that it did not.*

*Therefore, the answer to this question:*

> Am I sure that `onExit` is always invoked before global object(like `g_class`) destruction?

*Is **"Yes"**, as long as you are working with a fully-compliant compiler.*

---

> I've found `MyClass::~MyClass()` is invoked before `onExit()` in Visual Studio 2012.

If this is the case, then it is a **bug** in VC11. Per Paragraph 3.6.3/1 of the C++11 Standard:

> Destructors (12.4) for initialized objects (that is, objects whose lifetime (3.8) has begun) with static storage
>   duration are called as a result of returning from `main` and as a result of calling `std::exit` (18.5). [...]

Also, per Paragraph 3.6.3/3:

> If the completion of the initialization of an object with static storage duration is sequenced before a call
>   to `std::atexit` (see `<cstdlib>`, 18.5), **the call to the function passed to `std::atexit` is sequenced before the call to the destructor for the object.**

Therefore, in your case, `onexit()` should be invoked before the destructor of `MyClass`.

As far as I can tell, Clang 3.2 and GCC 4.8.0 are compliant in this respect, as shown in this [live example](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3kW04t%24370).

Comment: Whether g++ is compliant or not depends on the compiler options and the platform.  (It's compliant when it can be, but since on many platforms, the `atexit` function is supplied by the platform, it's not always reasonably possible.)

Comment: sorry. I wrote a mistake. onexit() is invoked before ~MyClass. I was so confused while tidying example code.

Comment: @zelon: OK. Then the behavior is correct and this is what the C++ Standard specifies.