# Using cout in destructors of static objects

Tags: c++, destructor, iostream, static-variables

Given this whittled down version of my code:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct S {
  S( ostream &os ) : os_( os ) { }
  ~S() { os_ << "The end.\n"; }         // line 7
  ostream &os_;
};

void f() {
  static S s( cout );
  (void)s;
}

int main() {
  f();
  return 0;
}
```

The program prints `The end.` However, as part of a larger program, it SEGFAULTS while attempting to write to the `ostream`.

I'm trying to ensure that some text will *always* get printed at program termination. Is what I'm trying to do legal using iostreams?  Would it be better to use `atexit(3)`?

I thought that because `cout` was constructed before my using it, that it would be destroyed after; so it's not clear why code like the above should't always work.

### Update

If I change line 7 to write to `cout` directly rather than via the reference, it works fine. That's even more bizarre.

Comment: Holding a reference to an object that you don't control the lifetime of seems like a bad idea to me.

Comment: @JonathanPotter `std::cout` is static just like the instance of `S` is, which is the reason why he's asking about the behavior.

Comment: There's no defined order in which static objects are created and destroyed, so you can't depend on `cout` being around when another static object is destroyed.

Comment: What?? I thought destruction of static objects is always done in reverse order of construction.

Comment: @PaulJ.Lucas I believe that only refers to objects with automatic storage duration.

Comment: Also, I think you're getting the correct output when you write to `std::cout` directly is because your program has Undefined Behavior somehow.

Comment: You probably want to check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/469597/destruction-order-of-static-objects-in-c

Comment: So if `cout` is constructed before first use and its first use is trigged by passing it by reference, that means it's constructed before `s`. That being the case, why isn't `cout` always destroyed after `s`?

Comment: I'm not sure what the standard says about this, but I know that some compilers don't consider passing a reference as 'first use.' The object has to actually be accessed. gcc is the biggest offender, though I'm not sure about latest versions.

Comment: Even if I add `os_ << "The beginning.\n"` in the constructor (which _has_ to be considered "first use"), it still crashes.

Answer (score 0):

If you call `atexit()` after the construction of the static object then the static object will be destroyed after the call to that object.  So yes using `atexit()` should resolve the problem.

See [Order between destruction of global object and atexit in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16010083/order-between-destruction-of-global-object-and-atexit-in-c)